# "The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Parameters" error is displayed for Cross-Browser Testing Script

Tags: java, selenium, cross-browser, automated-tests

I am trying this cross-browser testing using Selenium.

`CrossBrowser.java`:

```
package automationFramewok;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.beust.jcommander.Parameters;

// I am getting the following error on the next line
//
//   "The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Parameters"
//
@Parameters({"browser"})

public class CrossBrowser {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @BeforeTest

    public void setUp(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {

    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
       System.out.println("Running Firefox");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\\\Selenium-required files\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe");
       FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
       System.out.println("Running Chrome");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\\\\\\\Selenium-required files\\\\chromedriver\\\\chromedriver.exe");
       ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("opera")) {
       System.out.println("Running Opera");
    // driver = new OperaDriver();       --Use this if the location is set properly--
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("opera.binary", "C://Program Files (x86)//Opera//opera.exe");
       capabilities.setCapability("opera.log.level", "CONFIG");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "E:\\\\\\\\Selenium-required files\\\\operadriver\\\\operadriver.exe");
       OperaDriver driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
    }
    }
}
```

I am receiving the following error message:

> The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Parameters

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome! You might find this guide to formatting code in posts useful: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your list of import statements.  I think you want

```
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
```

and not

```
import com.beust.jcommander.Parameters;
```

Answer (score -1):

The same issue I was facing and problem was with import statement. I was using the following import statement.

```
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
```

Replaced with the following import statement and issue got resolved.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: Concept is same, but the annotations that I was using earlier was different and was causing the same issue.